# Trying to instantiate a class in a Jest test which normally extends a global class

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm working in a framework where a number of base classes are declared in the global scope and not imported.

For example:

File bar.js:

```js
export class Bar extends Foo {
}
```

Foo is never imported. When the framework runs, it adds class Foo to the global scope so when bar.js is loaded, Foo already exists in that global scope.

I'm trying to write a jest unit test for a class that extends one of these base classes. It always fails with  `ReferenceError: Foo is not defined`.

Here's what my unit test looks like:

```js
import { Bar } from '../lib/bar.js

describe('Bar', () => {
  test('has constructor', () => {
    let bar = new Bar()
    expect(bar).not.toBeNull()
  })
})
```

Is it possible to make this work? I've tried doing something like `global.Foo = class Foo {}` in my test file, but nothing I've tried has satisfied the reference to Foo in the file under test.

Comment: "*A number of base classes are declared in the global scope and not imported.*" - that sounds like a bad idea. Instead, consider writing a build chain tool (e.g. transpiler plugin) that *implicitly imports* these base classes where they are needed.

Comment: "*When the framework runs, it adds class Foo to the global scope*" - sounds like your framework didn't run in the unit test?

Comment: I can't change the framework. It is someone else's. When I run a unit test, I don't/can't run it inside the framework. 

I don't know what is meant by "writing a build chain tool (e.g. transpiler plugin) that implicitly imports these base classes where they are needed" nor do I know how to do that.

Comment: I recommend then to ask the author of the framework how they imagined testing. Btw I wasn't suggesting to run your test *inside* the framework, but you still need to somehow initialise the *global* framework before loading/importing `lib/bar.js` that depends on `Foo`. (The build chain tool suggestion was assuming you were the author of the framework, so this doesn't apply)

Comment: `global.Foo = class Foo {}` - this needs to be evaluated before files that rely on it are imported. The most simple way to achieve this in test file is to use `require` instead of `import` because the latter are hoisted by specs.